# WPF Storyboard with TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Storyboard such as

```
<Storyboard x:Key="NewsFlow">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" 
                                       RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="BlanchedAlmond"></Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="News" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>

</Grid>
```

Grid.Row="1" is News Viewing zone (yellow line)

But Storyboard ignored Grid.RowDefinitions like picture 
[image]

I want to like this

[image]

If you create a Storyboard should work like this:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="NewsFlow">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" 
                                       RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0,0,0,150"/>
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0, 150,0,0"/>
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

[image]

But Margin lagged behind TranslateTransform. And Textblock The other side is broken during the animation is played

Thank you, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="NewsFlow">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="News" 
                                       RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:00" Value="-80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:02" Value="80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="BlanchedAlmond"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="News" Text="News" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource NewsFlow}"/>
            </EventTrigger>                              
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```